# Signal handler changing global variable in c

Tags: c, process, global-variables, signals

A struct like this is created in my each of my child process.

```
struct locker_t {
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t user_id;
  uint8_t locked;
  uint8_t owned;
  int write_fd;
  int read_fd;
  int owner;
};
```

and I want my child process to be able to handle signal SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2. 
If a child recieves SIGUSR1 then change locker_t.locked into 1. A child also changes locker_t.locked into 0 if it recieves SIGUSR2.
So I created a global variable called int lockSig, and it equals to -1 to begin with. Also I created two signal handlers:

```
void lockHandler(int sig){
    lockSig=1;
}

void unlockHandler(int sig){
    lockSig=0;
}
```

I also have these 2 to recieve signals and change the lock:

```
signal(SIGUSR1,lockHandler);
signal(SIGUSR2,unlockHandler);
if(strcmp(buffer,"LOCK")==0||lockSig==1)//if lockSig is 1 then enter the if{
    lock.locked=1;
    fscanf(kid,"%d",&temp);//wait parent to run until gets an input
    lockSig=-1;//change back to -1, wait for next signal
}


if(strcmp(buffer,"UNLOCK")==0||lockSig==0)//if lockSig is 0 then enter the if{
    lock.locked=0;
    fscanf(kid,"%d",&temp);//wait parent to run until gets an input
    lockSig=-1;//change back to -1, wait for next signal
}
```

But  my program doesn't change the lock.locked. `I'm pretty sure the child gets the signal since I used printf to test it. I'm also using a infinite loop to read pipe inputs from parent and everything else works perfectly.` It's the first time for me using the signal handlers. I spent forvever on Google trying to figure out how to do it. Really need some help.

Comment: It's possible that the compiler has made optimizations that are not valid when `lockSig` can change like this. You should declare `lockSig` with the keyword `volatile`. Does that help?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I did. I even used volatile sig_atomic_t lockSig

Comment: Please reduce the problem to a complete program that others can try.